# Is it possible to increase history length on iPhone Safari?

Tags: iphone, safari

Is it possible on Safari for iPhone to increase the length of the browsing history? It seems to only keep one week of browsing history, which makes it hard to go back to stuff more than a week later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without a jailbreak of your iPhone.

The history should clear it's self twice in a month - but how the logic is (every 1. and 15. ??) - I don't know.

Comment: Even with jailbreak I don't know a solution.

Comment: I just thought that perhaps it could be a property file that needed to be adjusted - which is possible with jailbreak.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have more than 1 week of history... by upgrading the iPhone to iOS 7 or newer.

[On iOS 7, Safari keeps *roughly* 1 month of history.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173438/what-are-the-limits-of-the-history-on-safari-ios)